# JQuery load dynamic page in iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to load dynamic page into an iframe through navigation menus, if I choose menu option `FAQ`, iframe will located `faq.php` page to `src` attribute, and so on.

How could I dynamically assign menu's page into below?

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mainFrame").attr("src", "faq.php");
});
</script>


<div class="content">
    <div class="left">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Banking</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How To Join</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Recipe</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div>Title</div>
        <div><iframe src="" frameborder="0" id="mainFrame" name="mainFrame"></iframe></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you using a class for all you link as well as passing the name of the file you want to load in the iframe using data attribute:

```
<li><a class="anchor" data-url="faq.php" href="#">FAQ</a></li>
<li><a class="anchor" data-url="about.php" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a class="anchor" data-url="help.php" href="#">Help</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="anchor" data-url="subscribe.php" href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
        <li><a class="anchor" data-url="recipe.php" href="#">Recipe</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a class="anchor" data-url="term.php" href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
```

Then you can use jQuery to load the content of the iframe dynamically using:

```
$(".anchor").each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    el.click(function() {
        $("#mainFrame").attr("src", el.data('url'));
    })
})
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uSQhU/)**</kbd>

Comment: I'm intrigued. What's the benefit of doing `$(".anchor").each(function(){})` over just doing `$(".anchor").click(function(){})`?

Answer (score 3):

Simply like that :

```
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Banking</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">How To Join</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="faq">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Help</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Recipe</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div>Title</div>
            <div><iframe src="" frameborder="0" id="mainFrame" name="mainFrame"></iframe></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#faq").click(function () { 
      $("#mainFrame").attr("src", "faq.php");
});
</script>
```